# Retrieving data from a Nexus 6 motherboard

Tags: data-recovery, nexus-6

After a failed attempt to replace a broken screen on my Nexus 6, I was left with a Nexus 6 with a screen that no longer displayed anything. Yesterday, when I went to try to fix this I found that the battery had bloated out (exploded) which meant I had to throw the battery away.

All this now leaves me with a nexus 6 motherboard attached to a non-usable screen and no battery.

Since I am unsure at the moment if its the connection to the screen or the actual lcd that has broken. I don't want to spend money on new components to fix it (yet)..

So my question..

Is there anyway to retrieve data from the internal storage of a Nexus 6 from its motherboard alone?

If it were possible I'd imagine it would work in a similar way to using a laptop with the battery unplugged; powering the device from a usb cable and the fact that my android setting means that a computer would recognise it as a storage device so that I don't need to interact on the device at all..but then I don't know if usb alone would be enough to power the motherboard.

Comment: Did you have usb debugging enabled ?

Comment: @hg8 - Yes, I think I may have done but cannot remember if I did

Comment: you can try booting it, connecting it to your pc and run adb devices, if it shows up, you are lucky and you can retrieve data using something like `adb pull`

Comment: standard usb connections to a computer or laptop are as specified 500mA (0,5 ampere). that has to be enough. if you think It's not enough power, you will have to insert a battery and charge it before you connect....

Comment: @Schwertspize - will it still boot without a battery then? (like my laptop example?) I haven't tried yet since I was unsure if this would do further damage to either the "device" or less likely my pc. I know Nexus 6's are very power hungry but for the most part that was the display which was why i was unsure if it would work

Comment: first: you can't damage the device by providing too less power. and obviously you can't damage your laptop by powering your android... so if you do get a damaged device, the reason is your try to repair the display. and the "power hungry" thing: your stock battery has a theoretical capacity of 3220 mAh which would theoretically get charged in 6.44h via the theoretical 500 mA connection. just ask yourself the question: if it is fully charged, does it last longer than 6 hours of turned off display but active device. the answer is obviously "yes"

Comment: @Schwertspize - Thanks, I think i will nervously try it tomorrow on a computer at work. My worry was concerning whether or not the motherboard would know how to dissipate the power since it does not have a battery attached to divert it to

Comment: And yes, the charging electronic is way better than everything you can imagine, it **could easily handle power supply and no battery to charge.** but there may be the possibility that your damaged battery has physically damaged your power control and your processor or other components got accidentally too much power. if so, everything may be damaged now. this don't change by connecting to a power source. there is only the possibility of trying. And: just practice patience. give it enough time,....

Comment: @Schwertspize - Very plausible, another reason I don't fancy putting money towards something that could be a hopeless case